# XPS Viewer Setup wants to install KB932929. What is KB932929? No info available

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-update, xps-viewer

Today I downloaded and started to install Microsoft's XPS Viewer on a Windows Vista system.  When I started the installation process, one of the first things the Installer wanted to do is to install "**Update for Windows (KB932929)**".  But when I did an online search for that KB article number, I could find absolutely *no* information about what it does -- not even on the Microsoft websites.

Does anyone have any information about the purpose of KB932929, or where I might look to get some details about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Apparently it's **Windows6.0-KB932929 Microsoft XML Paper Specification Essentials Pack** which makes sense considering what you're trying to install.

Reference: http://www.ryanvm.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6228

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like that web page you found confirms that KB932929 is, in fact, just the XPS Viewer that I'm installing.  I still find it kind of curious that none of the Microsoft websites ever seem to mention that KB number explicitly though.  If you should find any MS web page that lists it, please let me know.  But, I'd say that you basically answered the question just by finding that posting on ryanvm.net.  So, thanks again.